# Provider MSDAORA is returning "?" instead of special characters

Tags: asp-classic, character-encoding, oracle11g

I'm having some problems trying to configure my computer to execute the application the same way that is in the server, the characters that are returned from the Oracle Database are shown as "?" instead of a special character.

My computer config is:

> Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bits
>
> IIS 7.5

The ASP pages are defined with ANSI encoding and have in the scope:

```
Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"
```

The provider used in the server, and consequently I have to use, is *MSDAORA*.

The oracle version is *11g*.

Did someone see this?

Comment: Recommended reading - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna read for sure.

Comment: It didn't work... the only difference between my computer and the server (that works without this issue) is the exibition language of the OS.

Comment: I don't know Oracle at all I'm afraid.  That has always worked for me with SQL Server and MySQL.  These days it's best to use utf-8 encoding throughout, but it could be that your database already contains ISO-8859-1 encoded text, in which case you could try `Response.CodePage = 1252` one line above `Response.CharSet = "ISO-8859-1"`